# KDE doesn't start up on Acer c720

Tags: 13.10, kde, chroot

My KDE is not starting after using the command `sudo startkde` I use it all the time and now is not working...

**Here is the output**

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startkde

Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/saucy...
Unknown username "whoopsie" in message bus configuration file

X.Org X Server 1.14.6
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Thu Feb 5 20:32:47 PST 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=043bcab0-1025-3e40-b108-a02541d36d19/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=043bcab0-1025-3e40-b108-a02541d36d19/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=fc1594ab211590d43d302cfb2fcb7ef567575211 salt=6f7abcac9e9a8bc67f0af849a4f05c0877bd62c2a61efde0bcb2887a186ab83c" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=043bcab0-1025-3e40-b108-a02541d36d19 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic iTCO_vendor_support.vendorsupport=3  
Build Date: 01 May 2014  09:47:30PM
xorg-server 2:1.14.6-0ubuntu1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Tue Feb 17 16:31:57 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
setversion 1.4 failed
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
setversion 1.4 failed
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /usr/bin/startkde
Running exit commands...
/usr/bin/xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/saucy...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well startkde is located at `/usr/local/bin/startkde` in the chroot (`/usr/local/chroots/CHROOTNAME/usr/local/bin/startkde`) but the crouton startup script tries to run `/usr/bin/startkde`.

That would explain `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /usr/bin/startkde`

Try this: `sudo enter-chroot -t kde xinit /usr/local/bin/startkde`

If that works, then the problem is the startup script. To fix it permanently run `sudo sed -i 's/\/usr\/bin\/startkde/\/usr\/local\/bin\/startkde/g' /usr/local/bin/startkde` from outside the chroot.